# Flutter GridView item wrap_content height

Tags: flutter, flutter-gridview

I am an android developer and new to flutter.

I would like to create a `GridView` with `wrap content` item height (I draw it with pen in the screenshot). But I have tried with the following code and it gave me only square grid item. I would like how to get height wrap content grid item and I have no idea and can't find how to get it. Please help. Thank you.

[image]

```
class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Category category;
  CategoryItem({Key key, @required this.category})
      : assert(category != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Text(
        category.name,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      color: Colors.amberAccent,
    );
  }
}


class CategoryGrid extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Category> items;

  const CategoryGrid({Key key, this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CategoryGridState createState() => _CategoryGridState();
}

class _CategoryGridState extends State<CategoryGrid> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            bottom: false,
            child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: widget.items.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 2 : 3,),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return CategoryItem(category: widget.items[index],);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

For height you can use "childAspectRatio"

For example-

```
GridView.count(
    childAspectRatio: 4.0,
    crossAxisCount: 2,

    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
            child: Text(
                '10:00 AM - 12:00 PM',
                style: new TextStyle( color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 14.0, 
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
            ), 
        );
    ],
    shrinkWrap: true,
    // todo comment this out and check the result
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! ush189 for help

Comment: childAspectRatio is a hardcoded value. I am running this code on horizontal tablet. If I test this on other screen size tablets, I am getting overflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap content grid item you can use the **childAspectRatio** property of gridview

Ex.

```
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: widget.items.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 2 : 3, childAspectRatio:(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.006)),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     return CategoryItem(category: widget.items[index],);
  },
)
```

you can set `childAspectRatio`  `0.006` instead of according to your content size

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `childAspectRatio` attribute of `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount` delegate to control the height with respect to width of the grid item.

If you just want to "shrink" the height (and something like `match_parent` for widhth) of the text widget wrap it around a `Column`, `Row` and `Expanded` like this

```dart
class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Category category;

  CategoryItem({Key key, @required this.category})
      : assert(category != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Card(
                child: Text(
                  category.name,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In GridView use this line

```
the childAspectRatio as per yor need 
childAspectRatio: double,
```